# How to get value of shared preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to retrieve the "entries" not the "entryValue" from a shared preference.  I am using this and it gets the entryValue:

```
String notifyInterval = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity).getString(ACCUWX.Preferences.PREF_NOTIFY_INTERVAL, null);
```

Here is the XML and array files:

```
<ListPreference
android:key="pref_temp_notifications"
android:title="@string/notifications"
android:entries="@array/pref_temp_notifications"
android:entryValues="@array/pref_temp_notifications_values"
android:dialogTitle="@string/notifications"
android:defaultValue="2"/>

<string-array name="pref_temp_notifications">
     <item>@string/my_current_location</item>
     <item>@string/home_location</item>
     <item>@string/off</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="pref_temp_notifications_values">
     <item>0</item>
     <item>1</item>
     <item>2</item>
</string-array>
```

So I'd like to retrieve the string value, not the numeric.  The numeric is what I get returned and assigned to my variable notifyInterval.  How do I grab the text?

Comment: Why not just replace `0,1,2` with the string values

Comment: I don't do that because there are other preferences that I need both a string value and an integer value for calculations in code.

Comment: getAll() method of SharedPreferences will return you all key-value pairs. From this map you can get all key values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use getAll () method which returns Map, from that map, get KeySet which returns entries of shared preference.

```
Map<String, ?> test = getAll ();
Set keySet = test.keySet();

Iterator<String> keySetIter = keySet .iterator();
  while (keySetIter.hasNext()) {
  String keyEntry= keySetIter.next();
}
```

Comment: I think that is what you are looking for? Do you know the key to get sharedpreferences? If so, you can use something like this,  If your value is Integer you need to use getInt() instead of getBoolean(....)      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);

Comment: This returns the entryValue and I need the entries.  I can do it in my activity that extends PreferenceActivity like this, where "key" is my preference: Preference pref = findPreference(key);
  String currentPrefValue = null;
     if (pref instanceof ListPreference) {
         ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) pref;
         currentPrefValue = (listPref.getEntry()).toString();
         Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "current pref value in onSharedPreferenceChanged is " + currentPrefValue);
     }

Comment: There is a method called getEntryValues(), did you try that? listPref.getEntryValues().